# select duplicate records where one record must contain the exact value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table as below with 3 columns amount, frequency & identifier. All these records are in the same table in the same database.

```
amount     frequency       identifier
4.75        1                100
4.75        3                101
4.76        2                102
4.76        3                103
4.44        1                104
4.43        1                105
4.75        2                106
4.67        2                107
4.75        3                108
4.64        2                109
4.64        3                110
4.65        4                111
```

I'm after a sql query that should pickup duplicate records for different frequency but frequency of one of them must be equal to 1. So the output i'm expecting is

```
amount  frequency   identifier
4.75        1       100
4.75        3       101
4.75        2       106
4.75        3       108
```

Note that the query is executed every 2 seconds along with 15 other queries that are lightweight. I can do the processing in php too, but prefer a database query so long its not performance intensive. I'm trying different queries, but can't get consistent results. Can someone please help ?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking something like this would be the fastest way to get what you want:

```
select *
from t
where exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.amount = t.amount and t2.frequency = 1)
```

This will run fastest with an index on `(amount, frequency)`.